# when notification alert comes from broadcast receiver it reopens the application

Tags: android, notifications

How to implement  code for stopping the reopening application from
  notification here is my code.
 when myapplication is minimized,it reopens the last activity

> **extends broadcast receiver class**
>
> ```
> Intent newIntent = new Intent(con, NotificationAlertForStopper.class);
>         newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
>         newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
>         newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
>         con.startActivity(newIntent);
> ```
>
> **NotificationAlertForStopper.java**
>
> ```
> public class NotificationAlertForStopper extends Activity
> {
>   private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
>   private int SIMPLE_NOTFICATION_ID;
>   String getTime="0",aaa;
>   CharSequence contentTitle, contentText;
>    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer,mediaPlayer1;
>    MyDataBase mdb;
>    ArrayList<MoodsTimings> values;
>    String dy;
>    private final int SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGHT = 15000;
>
>   @Override
>   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
>           final Notification notifyDetails = new Notification(R.drawable.appicon,"xxxxxxx",System.currentTimeMillis());
>
>
>           int resID1=getResources().getIdentifier("relax", "raw", getPackageName());
>
>                mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(NotificationAlertForStopper.this,resID1);
>                mediaPlayer.start();
>                mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
>
>
>
>                int resID2=getResources().getIdentifier("inhale", "raw", getPackageName());
>
>                mediaPlayer1=MediaPlayer.create(NotificationAlertForStopper.this,resID2);
>                mediaPlayer1.start();
>                mediaPlayer1.setLooping(true);
>
>                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
>                   @Override
>                   public void run() {
>                       mediaPlayer.stop();
>                       mediaPlayer1.stop();
>                       mNotificationManager.cancel(SIMPLE_NOTFICATION_ID);
>                   }
>               }, SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGHT);
>           /* try {
>                   Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
>                   Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), notification);
>                   r.play();
>               } catch (Exception e) {}*/
>
>           Context context = getApplicationContext();
>
>               contentTitle = "xxxxx";
>               contentText = "xxxxxxxxxxxx Breathe";
>
>               Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(this,Meditation.class);
>               notifyIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
>               PendingIntent intent = 
>                   PendingIntent.getActivity(NotificationAlertForStopper.this, 0, 
>                   notifyIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
>
>
>
>
>
>           notifyDetails.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, intent);
>           mNotificationManager.notify(SIMPLE_NOTFICATION_ID, notifyDetails);
>           //mNotificationManager.cancel(SIMPLE_NOTFICATION_ID);
>           finish();
>
>   }
>
>
> }
> ```

Comment: do you just want the notification to dissapear and nothing else when you click on it?

Comment: if so after final Notification notifyDetails = new Notification(R.drawable.appicon,"xxxxxxx",System.currentTimeMillis()); try to put notifyDetails.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you have written this `Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(this,Meditation.class);` in onCreate() of your activity.

The basic flow should be once the notification appears in notification tray of your device,clicking on that should open up your activity.

Answer (score 0):

## Possible Way:

on extends broadcast receiver class

Intent newIntent = new Intent(con, NotificationAlertForStopper.class);

con.**startService**(newIntent);

then

public class NotificationAlertForStopper extends **Service**